# Prove that there exists at least one $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x_0)+f''(x_0)=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function, two times
>   differentiable with $\left|f(x)\right|\leq1,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$
>   and $f^2(0)+\left(f'(0)\right)^2=4$. Prove that there exists at least
>   one $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x_0)+f''(x_0)=0$.

I have tried the usual Rolle method by $e^x$, but didn't go far... Any help available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define $g(x) = f(x)^2 + f'(x)^2$. We have:

- $g'(x) = 2f'(x)(f(x)+f''(x))$
- $g(0) = 4$

We will find a local maximum of $g$, noted $x_0$, which verifies $g(x_0) \ge 4$. We shall distinguish two options:

- $g(0) = 4 \ge g(x) \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}$, in which case $0$ is the local maximum that we are trying to find.
- There exists $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ with $g(y) > 4$. Let's supose that $y > 0$ (otherwise apply the following reasoning to $-g$) and try to find a number $x' > y$ which verifies $g(x') = 4$. If there isn't such a number, then we would have $g(x) > 4$ for every $x > y$. Thus, $\left| f'(x) \right| > \sqrt 3$ for every $x > y$. Using the mean value theorem on $x > \max\{2,y\}$ we get a contradiction:

$$ 2 \ge \left| f(x) - f(0)\right| = \left| f'(\xi_x) \ x \right| > 2 \sqrt 3 > 2 $$

As a consequence, we can take $x' > y$ with $g(x') = 4$. The function $g$ has a global maximum in $[0, x']$ because it is continuous. Let $x_0$ be that global maximum. Then, $g(x_0) \ge g(y) > 4$ and, consequently, $x_0 \ne 0, x'$. Hence, $x_0$ is a local maximum of $g$ with $g(x_0) \ge 4$.

Finally, since $x_0$ is a local extrema we have:

$$ 0 = g'(x_0) = 2f'(x_0)(f(x_0)+f''(x_0)) $$

Furthermore, $f'(x_0)^2 \ge 4 - f(x_0)^2 \ge 3 > 0$ and, thus, $f(x_0)+f''(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: Can you clarify your arguments for the contradiction? Specifically, why must we find such a number $x_n$ and why if $f'$ is not bounded, then $f$ is also not bounded?

Comment: You are assuming that if $g$ has no global maximum then it is unbounded. But $g$ may be bounded and NOT have a global maximum. For example, $g(x)=\tan ^{-1} x$

Comment: @Chilango Do you have any proof for my exercise? Because nothing has been done yet...

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I repaired the solution. Note that the function $f(x) = \sin(2e^x -1)$ verifies the hypothesis and the derivative is not bounded, that was a mistake.

Comment: Why must we have $g(x)>4$ for every $x>y$ in your second case and not $g(x)<4$?

Comment: Also, after the "as a consequence" Rolle's theorem would provide a shorter proof.

Comment: If $g(x) < 4$ for every $x > y$, then just use that $g$ is continuous and $g(y) > 4 > g(x)$ to find the number $x'$ between $y$ and $x$.

Comment: You can't use Rolle's theorem there because you need $g(x_0) \ge 4$ and in order to affirm that you should $x_0$ as the global maximum of $[0,x']$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the interval $[-2,0]$.

By LMVT $$|f'(c)|=\left|\frac{f(0)-f(-2)}{0-(-2)}\right|\leq\frac{|f(0)|+|f(-2)|}{2}\leq 1$$ for some $c\in(-2,0)$,

$$\Rightarrow g(c)=(f(c))^2+(f'(c))^2\leq 1+1$$ i.e. $g(c)\leq 2$.

Similarly, on the interval $[0,2]$ we have $g(d)\leq 2$ for some $d\in (0,2)$ .

So on the interval $(c,d)$ we have a point of local/global maximum at $x=x_0\in(c,d)$ since $g(0)=4$.

So $g(x_0)\geq 4$ and thus we must have  $g'(x_0)=0$ since $g(x)$ is twice differentiable.

$$g'(x_0)=2f'(x_0)(f(x_0)+f''(x_0))=0.$$

We can't have $f'(x_0)=0$ because in that case $g(x_0)=(f(x_0))^2+(f'(x_0))^2\leq 1+0\leq 1$. But $g(x_0)\geq 4$.

So, the only option that we have is $f(x_0)+f''(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\in(-2,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore the extrema of 
$$
g(x)=f(x)^2+f'(x)^2\implies g'(x)=2f'(x)(f(x)+f''(x)).
$$

Comment: What about another, more specific, hint?