# Prove $\exists \xi \in (-2,2):f(\xi)+f''(\xi)=0.$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

## Problem

Let $f(x)$ be twice-differentiable over $[-2,2]$, $|f(x)|\leq 1$ and $f^2(0)+[f'(0)]^2=4.$ Prove that $\exists \xi \in (-2,2):f(\xi)+f''(\xi)=0.$

## My Proof

First，by Lagrange' Mean Value Theorem，we have
$$\exists \xi_1 \in (-2,0),\xi_2 \in (0,2):f'(\xi_1)=\frac{f(0)-f(-2)}{2},f'(\xi_2)=\frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2}.$$
Thus
$$|f'(\xi)|\leq \frac{|f(0)|+|f(-2)|}{2}\leq \frac{1+1}{2}=1,$$
and likewise
$$|f'(\xi_2)|\leq 1.$$
Denote$$F(x):=f^2(x)+[f'(x)]^2.$$
It's easy to verify that $F(x)$ is continuous and differentiable over $[\xi_1,\xi_2]$. Therefore, $F(x)$ can reach its maximum value over the interval above. But
$$F(\xi_1)\leq 1+f'^2(\xi_1)\leq 2<F(0),$$
and similarily
$$F(\xi_2)\leq 2<F(0),$$
the maximum value can not come out at the end points of the interval.Hence, it must be taken over $(\xi_1,\xi_2)$. Let the point be $x=\xi\in(\xi_1,\xi_2)\subset (-2,2)$. Then
$$F'(\xi)=0,$$
which implies that
$$2f'(\xi)[f(\xi)+f''(\xi)]=0.$$

Now, Notice that $$4\leq F(\xi)=f^2(\xi)+f'^2(\xi)\leq 1+f'^2(\xi),$$
which implies $f'(\xi)\geq 3$，and hence$f'(\xi) \neq 0$. It follows that
$$f(\xi)+f''(\xi)=0,$$
which is desired.

**Please correct if I'm wrong. Hope to see other solutions. THX.**

Comment: Same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685616/prove-that-there-exists-at-least-one-x-0-in-mathbbr-such-that-fx-0fx